# Advantages of using Openstack Heat with Chef

Tags: chef-infra, openstack

As Chef and Openstack Heat both are used for orchestration of infrastructure on cloud or physical servers, what is the purpose behind using Chef along with Openstack Heat? What advantage will it provide over the scenario in which only OpenStack Heat is used(without Chef)?

Comment: Chef is not an orchestration framework. It's a configuration management and automation framework.

Comment: @sethvargo thanks for pointing out that difference, but what is the exact difference between orchestration and configuration management ?

Comment: You manage the configuration of a single machine. You orchestrate the connections between them. There are some Chef tools (like flock of chefs) that permit a lower-level of orchestration. Chef metal also looks promising.

Comment: +1 for Chef-metal.  We were on the fence between Openstack Heat and Chef-metal but after testing metal turned out to be the better option.

Comment: This question still seems relevant. If I have Chef and OpenStack, why would I use Heat templates?

Answer (score 0):

Heat templates can be used for creating VMs, networks, routers, volumes etc.  Chef is then used inside a VM to install/configure the packages.

**What can chef do that heat does?**

There is overlap between heat templates and "chef provisioning" https://docs.chef.io/provisioning.html (formerly "chef metal"), but support for openstack within chef provisioning is not yet very good.

**What can heat do that chef does?**

In terms of getting Heat templates to do package management etc, you can use cloud-init from within the heat template to install packages. For this, set the user_data on your OS::Nova::Server either to an OS::Heat::SoftwareConfig or maybe to an OS::Heat::MultipartMime that contains a few configs. From that you can either use the "packages" module or possibly via runcmd (see https://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/examples.html. I've found packages/runcmd most useful when you need some things on the system before chef runs, e.g. some gems which get used by a custom chef handler.